# RETAG: games <-> puzzles ?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

We have one post tagged with [games](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games), and 4 tagged with [puzzles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzles). Do we need two separate tags for them ?

Proposal: RETAG the one games-tagged post ([on international draughts](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/is-it-np-hard-to-play-international-draughts-correctly)) as puzzles.

I'd create a tag synonym for voting, but my AMP will force creation, and I'd rather get the community opinion.

**Update**: Correctly, people have pointed out that games is a generic name that applies to too many settings to be merged with puzzles, and that for this particular example, board-games might be a better tag. So I'm closing this request.

Comment: Or maybe a new tag that encompasses both? like "recreational"?

Comment: that's also a possibility.

Comment: Maybe board games is an accurate description of many of the problems Bob Hearn and John Conway have worked on.  I'm not sure recreational quite captures their essence.

Comment: so board-games seems like a good tag then. I'll retag that specific question and withdraw the general request.

Answer (score 1):

I oppose to the merge because I view games and puzzles as different things, although puzzles can be formulated as 1-player games in some cases.  For example, it is confusing if a question about checkers/draughts is tagged as “puzzles.”

(Also, as a researcher working on multi-prover interactive proof systems (with some quantum twists), I may post a question about multi-player cooperative games in the future.  I can imagine that the question will not be related to puzzles at all.)

Comment: At least on the second point, that would be a game-theory tag, not games or puzzles

Comment: @Suresh: That may be a good point, but I am not sure if the study of games as in the computational complexity theory (such as [games against nature](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000%2885%2990045-5)) is considered as part of the game theory.

Comment: @Suresh: I agree with Tsuyoshi. Classes like RG (Refereed Games) are about computational games, and results about them, like RG = EXP are complexity results. I don't think it would count as game theory.

Comment: Another example: Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games that are used in finite model theory would probably be uninteresting to people looking at puzzles.

Comment: I don't think a single "game" tag would work. Different people seem to assign different meanings to it. Each of the cases mention above should have a more specific tag, e.g. EF-games or Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé-games would be more suitable for FMT setting, I don't think any FMTist would look under games tag for them. In summery, I think "games" is too general to be useful as a tag.